# Super Evil New Tab - Loading Local Image Files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html

Trying to set webpage background image via Javascript:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('file:///C:/Users/[user]/Documents/BadConnectionBackground.jpeg')";
```

This statement works if I use an imgur image's url, but has not worked for any local files - I just get a black page. If I copy and past the url above into my browser it loads the image just fine. I am using a Chrome extension "Super Evil New Tab" to modify chrome's new tab page, perhaps this has something to do with it?

Comment: If your webpage is loaded through HTTP protocol then Chrome's security policy will kick in and prevent the page to load any local assets.

Comment: Right-click the extension icon in the browser toolbar, click "Manage extensions", enable "Allow access to file URLs". This question is off-topic on StackOverflow, though.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't see an option to allow filesystem access in the extension menu. I only have "Allow in incognito".

Comment: I've looked thoroughly, it seems that the best option is to always launch chrome with the "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag

Comment: Sorry, this option is only shown for extensions that declare `<all_urls>` or `activeTab` host permissions.

Comment: Hey there,

I'm the creator of the mentioned extension.

I'm going to publish an update to the store with the `activeTab` permission,
so you can access local files.